# this code is showing error in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

This Jade code isn't working.

```
head
    script(src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js')
    script(src='http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js')

body
    script(type='text/javascript')
        var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
        var data = [
        { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
        { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
        ];
        var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
        chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
        chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
        chart.draw();
```

Comment: You'll need to type out full questions - for example, please can someone what? What error is it showing? What have you tried?

Comment: Why you embedding javascript in template in first place. I can understand this in CustomElements or AJAX html parts but in whole site this shouldn't happen. Especially in JADE template, where this don't look well or readable.

Answer (score 0):

As of [version 1.0.0](http://jade-lang.com/history/#1-0-0-2013-12-22) of Jade, you must include a `.` to make `script` tags be text:

```
body
    script(type='text/javascript').
        // above here
        var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
        var data = [
        { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
        { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
        ];
        var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
        chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
        chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
        chart.draw();
```

Comment: I am trying to create a pie chart using jade template the problem it showing is "undefined text ;" in line 12 after removing all the semi-colons it will show just a blank screen but the same code will work perfect in html